# Lock free multiple reader, single writer Linked List

Tags: lockless

I have been exploring various solutions online for lockless/lock free linked lists. I have come across techniques like RCU, hazard pointers, and publications on auxilary nodes / "marking" nodes, etc to solve this problem. They all solve concurrency issues for multiple writers and readers.
Before pursuing any of these solutions, I wanted to check if there are any simpler, standard techniques to develop lock free algorithms , for single writer - multiple reader linked lists.
(supported operations are Add, delete, find and update)

Thanks for your time.
Sri

Answer (score -1):

In my idea you can use client/server  design for read and write , If you have only 1 writer .